# Method undefined for type?

Tags: java, methods, undefined

I'm doing a weather processor assignment for my computer science class, and I'm having some trouble with a piece of the code. I'm not sure how to approach the issue, so any help would be great. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Info {

    Object data;
    String weatherRecord[][][] = new String[0][0][0];
    int index = 0;
    int HIGHS, LOWS, WIND, GUST, PRECIP;

    public void weatherData () {
        data = data;
    }

    final String[] locationNames = {"Eagle, NE", "New York, NY", "Houston, TX", "Los Angeles, CA"};
    final int[] monthLength = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}; 

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < weatherRecord.length; i++) {
            GregorianCalendar dateInfo = new GregorianCalendar(2008, 0, 1);
            System.out.println((dateInfo.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+ "/" +
                        dateInfo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+ "/" +
                        dateInfo.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            for (int j = 0; j < weatherRecord[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < monthLength[j]; k++) {

                    weatherRecord[i][j][k] = new weatherData();
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setLocation(locationNames[i]);
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setDate((GregorianCalendar) dateInfo.clone());
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setHighTemp(data.getHIGHS(index));
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setLowTemp(data.getLOWS(index));
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setWind(data.getWIND(index));
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setGust(data.getGUST(index));
                    weatherRecord[i][j][k].setPrecip(data.getPRECIP(index));
                    index++;
                    dateInfo.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                }

                System.out.println((dateInfo.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" +
                            dateInfo.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                            dateInfo.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            }
        }
    }   

    private int setLocation(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The part I'm having the trouble with is the data.getHIGHS/LOWS/etc, it tells me that the `getHIGHS` method is undefined for the type Object. Where am I going wrong? I have another class that has the getters for the methods in this code.

Comment: You're calling getHIGHS() on `data`. `data` is a variable of type Object. Object doesn't have any getHIGHS method. As simple as that.

Comment: You define your `weatherRecord`  structure as several arrays of `String` at the top of the file; these objects don't have a `getHIGHS` method.  Later you try to re-define the _k_th dimention to be the object returned by `new weatherData()`.  I'm assuming `new weatherData()` returns some other structure?

Answer (score 2):

The error message means simple that the Object class has no method called **getHIGHS**, at least not the `java.lang.Object`

Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

It could be possible that you are using some kind of lib that has an Object class, then you have to import that package....

But I will suggest to take a look at the documentation if you are using 3rd part libs.